# C++ pattern for multiple "worker classes" that manipulate a large data class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a single very large data class (really a struct, honestly), which needs to be manipulated in enough different ways that I don't just want to implement all of the manipulators as member methods of the data class.

Right now, I have the manipulators set up as singletons, or small instantiated classes held by some manager object, and I pass every manipulator a pointer to the data class during initialization.  This works, but feels a little sloppy to me.

One complicating issue is that the manipulators have state.  One example of manipulator state that could be factored out of the manipulators themselves is thread-safety helpers (mutexes/semaphores), but there are other data members that logically belong to the manipulators so I don't think this problem is going away.

So I'm wondering, is there some design pattern that can provide a cleaner solution for this situation?

Comment: Does the "struct" need to be that big - or could it benefit from a more digestable data structure

Comment: The struct is already broken up into smaller logical pieces, but manipulation needs to happen on a large scale.  For example, one "manipulation" may need to move sub-data from one of the "smaller logical pieces" to another.  Furthermore this needs to be very fast, so adding many layers of abstraction is an iffy proposition.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear to me what is the complicating issue and what you need to go away.

Answer (score 1):

[A factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) could be used with the factory offering a method taking a pointer or reference to the data, and a value (possibly enumeration) indicating the operation to be performed, it then selects the agent that can perfrom that operation and asks it to do so.

As for the states, if the agents' states are synchronised then a single state in the factory would be fine - if they are not then the factory could simply provide a method to be called in the event that anything happens that could change any agent's state and inform all the agents.  Or, the agents could themselves be [observers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) of whatever it is that causes the state changes.

As for implementing a state machine - that's also often done using a factory pattern!  So you **could** have a factory of factories where each sub factory is also an observer.  This would be almost too awesome for words.